# Can anyone recommend a peirush on the peirush haGra on Sefer Mishlei?

Tags: product-recommendation, vilna-gaon, mishlei

I sat in a weekly shiur on the peirush haGra on Mishlei for years and I took out a tremendous amount - my Rosh Yeshiva gave over many deep yesodos of life but I found it was very hard to pick up a derech in how to learn up the sefer myself, and I want to be able to go through the sefer myself. I understand that there's no replacement for learning with a chevrusa, which I iyH will be able to find - but can anyone recommend a peirush that might help make the text more accessible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is a sefer [זה השער](https://www.eichlers.com/zh-hwer-mwli-prqim-a-b-wpira-hs40263.html) of Rav Moshe Shapira's shuirim on the Goan on Mishlei. It is several hundred pages long, and barely makes it out of the first perek. It is mostly discussing and elaborating on the concepts beyond the text of the Goan.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, Rav Meir Twersky has [online shiurim](https://ravtwersky.torahweb.org/vilna-gaon-on-sefer-mishlei/) on the first three perakim in Mishlei on the Gr"a's peirush.